# non-negative curvature of space curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, global-analysis

I read in most of the textbook that "curvature of a space curve is always non-negative" but I could not understand the intuition behind this that why is so? Give some nice intuition and proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Because if $c$ is parametrised by arc-length it‘s curvature is defined as $\kappa(s):=||c‘‘(s)||.$

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of definition. Only for a plane curve can you define *signed curvature*: You use a right-handed frame $T(s),N(s)$ (tangent, principal normal at $\alpha(s)$) and curvature is positive if the curve is bending towards $N$, negative if it's bending away from $N$. In more than two dimensions, you always define $N(s)$ to be in the direction of $T'(s)$ (assuming it's nonzero), and $\kappa$ is then the magnitude of this vector.